# Is it possible to get Directory list and filter by owner?

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to get directory list with specific owner.

To get directory list without filtering,

```
foreach(var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
{
  ....
}
```

However, is it possible to filter by owner? I cannot find owner related function in LINQ

```
foreach(var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Where(....))
{
  ....
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can:

```
var list=directoryInfo.GetDirectories().Cast<DirectoryInfo>()
                      .Where(x=> System.IO.File.GetAccessControl( x.FullName)
                                       .GetOwner(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount)).ToString()
                                       .Contains("Administrators"));
```